# SharePoint Syntax for Completed calculated field

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm new to using SharePoint online and have two columns titled Status and Manager Approval. If both are equal to 'Completed', I want the Completed (calculated field) on the task list to mark the task as complete. However, I can't find the right syntax to do so. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There you go:

```
=IF(AND([Status] = "Completed", [Manager Approval] = "Completed"),"Completed","")
```

Comment: Thank you!! I gave you a point on the left but I'm too new for it to appear :(